# Bolding a specific part of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell that is referenced as `="Dealer: " & CustomerName`.
CustomerName is a dictionary referenced name. How could I go along of bolding only "Dealer:" and not the Customer name.

Example:

**Dealer:** Josh

I have tried

```
Cells(5, 1).Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
```

But it only seems to work on non referenced cells only. How could I get this to work on a referenced cell?

Comment: If you cannot achieve it manually then you can be pretty sure that this cannot be achieved using VBA either.

Comment: You cannot apply character-formatting to the results of a **formula**

Comment: A5 has 'Dealer' in bold and B5 has `=CustomerName`.  All works, no VBA required.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook that doesn't necessarily work as B5 column length on my template can't be expanded enough for the result.

Comment: What's a "referenced/non-referenced cell"?

Comment: Simple minded idea: have `Dealer` in one cell, and the data in the other. Play around with column widths, gridlines and cell outlines, etc. so that it *appears* to be one cell.

Comment: @JohnColeman that's actually **the** most semantically correct way to go about it.

Comment: If you can't use different cells as @JohnColeman proposed (+1), you can attach an image with bold text.

Comment: Would you please let us know if `CustomerName`is a Defined Name in your workbook? If so what's its scope (i.e. workbook or worksheet)? or It's a Variable in a VBA Procedure? What it is?

Comment: I am a bit confused .. how can 1 rep user offer 150 rep bounty? You can probably use unicode bold letters if you are ok with the different font = ": " & CustomerName (note that it is not bold formatting but just unicode characters) http://qaz.wtf/u/

Comment: @Slai That is a good idea. But it seems that Unicode bold isn't universally supported. Excel (especially pre-2016) generally and VBA particularly is somewhat weak with Unicode support. For example, I tried to use `chrW()` to put a Unicode math bold A in cell `A1` and it threw an error. Perhaps I was doing it wrong, but preliminary experiments aren't encouraging. If you can make it work, perhaps you could post it as an answer. (By the way -- I suspect that OP started with a rep of 151. The rep hit happens when you set a bounty).

Comment: @JohnColeman works for me as Excel formula `= ": " & 123` on Excel 2007 with fonts that support that Unicode range

Comment: @I was trying to write a user defined function in VBA that could create such a thing automatically, where it would take a passed string and use `chrW` to convert alphanumeric ascii symbols to bold equivalents. `chrW` didn't like the Unicode code points that I was able to find for bold letters. I'll experiment more. Why don't you post your idea as an answer?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am not fully sure what the question is and if it has to be in VBA. It needs more than 2 bytes per character `[a1] = ChrW(55349) & ChrW(56320)` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d400

Answer (score 16):

You can use the below function to bold some input text within a formula

So in your cell you can now type =Bold("Dealer: ")&CustomerName

To be precise – this will only embolden alphabetical characters (a to z and A to Z) all others will be left unchanged. I haven’t tested it on different platforms, but seems to work on mine. May not be supported for all fonts.

```
 Function Bold(sIn As String)
    Dim sOut As String, Char As String
    Dim Code As Long, i As Long
    Dim Bytes(0 To 3) As Byte

    Bytes(0) = 53
    Bytes(1) = 216

    For i = 1 To Len(sIn)
        Char = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        Code = Asc(Char)
        If (Code > 64 And Code < 91) Or (Code > 96 And Code < 123) Then
            Code = Code + IIf(Code > 96, 56717, 56723)
            Bytes(2) = Code Mod 256
            Bytes(3) = Code \ 256
            Char = Bytes
        End If
        sOut = sOut & Char
    Next i
    Bold = sOut
End Function
```

Edit:

Have made an effort to refactor the above to show how it works, rather than have it peppered with magical numbers.

```
  Function Bold(ByRef sIn As String) As String
     ' Maps an input string to the Mathematical Bold Sans Serif characters of Unicode
     ' Only works for Alphanumeric charactes, will return all other characters unchanged

     Const ASCII_UPPER_A As Byte = &H41
     Const ASCII_UPPER_Z As Byte = &H5A
     Const ASCII_LOWER_A As Byte = &H61
     Const ASCII_LOWER_Z As Byte = &H7A
     Const ASCII_DIGIT_0 As Byte = &H30
     Const ASCII_DIGIT_9 As Byte = &H39
     Const UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_UPPER_A As Long = &H1D5D4
     Const UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_LOWER_A As Long = &H1D5EE
     Const UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_DIGIT_0 As Long = &H1D7EC

     Dim sOut As String
     Dim Char As String
     Dim Code As Long
     Dim i As Long

     For i = 1 To Len(sIn)
        Char = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        Code = AscW(Char)
        Select Case Code
           Case ASCII_UPPER_A To ASCII_UPPER_Z
              ' Upper Case Letter
              sOut = sOut & ChrWW(UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_UPPER_A + Code - ASCII_UPPER_A)
           Case ASCII_LOWER_A To ASCII_LOWER_Z
              ' Lower Case Letter
              sOut = sOut & ChrWW(UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_LOWER_A + Code - ASCII_LOWER_A)
           Case ASCII_DIGIT_0 To ASCII_DIGIT_9
              ' Digit
              sOut = sOut & ChrWW(UNICODE_SANS_BOLD_DIGIT_0 + Code - ASCII_DIGIT_0)
           Case Else:
              ' Not available as bold, return input character
              sOut = sOut & Char
        End Select
     Next i
     Bold = sOut
  End Function

  Function ChrWW(ByRef Unicode As Long) As String
     ' Converts from a Unicode to a character,
     ' Includes the Supplementary Tables which are not normally reachable using the VBA ChrW function

     Const LOWEST_UNICODE As Long = &H0              '<--- Lowest value available in unicode
     Const HIGHEST_UNICODE As Long = &H10FFFF        '<--- Highest vale available in unicode
     Const SUPPLEMENTARY_UNICODE As Long = &H10000   '<--- Beginning of Supplementary Tables in Unicode. Also used in conversion to UTF16 Code Units
     Const TEN_BITS As Long = &H400                  '<--- Ten Binary Digits - equivalent to 2^10. Used in converstion to UTF16 Code Units
     Const HIGH_SURROGATE_CONST As Long = &HD800     '<--- Constant used in conversion from unicode to UTF16 Code Units
     Const LOW_SURROGATE_CONST As Long = &HDC00      '<--- Constant used in conversion from unicode to UTF16 Code Units

     Dim highSurrogate As Long, lowSurrogate As Long

     Select Case Unicode
        Case Is < LOWEST_UNICODE, Is > HIGHEST_UNICODE
           ' Input Code is not in unicode range, return null string
           ChrWW = vbNullString
        Case Is < SUPPLEMENTARY_UNICODE
           ' Input Code is within range of native VBA function ChrW, so use that instead
           ChrWW = ChrW(Unicode)
        Case Else
           ' Code is on Supplementary Planes, convert to two UTF-16 code units and convert to text using ChrW
           highSurrogate = HIGH_SURROGATE_CONST + ((Unicode - SUPPLEMENTARY_UNICODE) \ TEN_BITS)
           lowSurrogate = LOW_SURROGATE_CONST + ((Unicode - SUPPLEMENTARY_UNICODE) Mod TEN_BITS)
           ChrWW = ChrW(highSurrogate) & ChrW(lowSurrogate)
     End Select

  End Function
```

For reference on the unicode characters used see here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/list.htm

The wikipedia page on UTF16 shows the algorithm for converting from Unicode to two UTF16 code points

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: OP should accept this answer :-)
Kept it in my "code library", thanks!

Comment: My idea was for the Unicode characters to be directly used in the Excel formula as I can't imagine any practical use for this in VBA. For anyone using this approach, note that the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols Unicode Block (U+1D400 to U+1D7FF) has Sans bold version (for fonts like Arial) and Sans-serif bold version (for fonts like Times New Roman) http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Dealer. Either way, the bold characters will look a tiny bit different than the rest of the text (unless the same Unicode range is used for the rest of the characters)

Comment: Looks magical, how does it work please?  Some reference to documentation would be great.

Comment: It uses the mathematical sans-serif bold unicode characters. Documentation on the capital A  can be found here
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d5d4/index.htm.

Note that the character takes up 4 bytes in memory. Normally for converting between character codes and strings you could use the Chr or ChrW functions, but these will only codes length 1 or 2 bytes respectively. So instead I've used a Byte array where I calculate the codes manually and then copy them over to a string.

Answer (score 2):

As they already told you can't format a partial cell value if this latter derives from a formula/function in that same cell

However there may be some workarounds that may suit your needs

Unluckily I can't actually grasp your real *environment* so here are some blind shots:

---

**1st "environment"**

You have a VBA code running that at some point writes in a cell like:

```
Cells(5, 1).Formula = "=""Dealer: "" & CustomerName"
```

and you want to have the `"Dealer:"` part bold

- the most straightforward way would then be

  ```
  With Cells(5, 1)
      .Formula = "=""Dealer: "" & CustomerName"
      .Value = .Value
      .Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
  End With
  ```
- but you could also use the `Worksheet_Change()` event handler as follows:

  your VBA code is only

  ```
  Cells(5, 1).Formula = "=""Dealer: "" & CustomerName"
  ```

  while placing the following code in the relevant worksheet code pane:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      With Target
          If Left(.Text, 7) = "Dealer:" Then
              Application.EnableEvents = False '<-- prevent this macro to be fired again and again by the statement following in two rows
              On Error GoTo ExitSub
              .Value = .Value
              .Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
          End If
      End With

  ExitSub:
      Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- get standard event handling back
  End Sub
  ```

  where `On Error GoTo ExitSub` and `ExitSub: Application.EnableEvents = True` shouldn't be necessary, but I left them as a good practice when `Application.EnableEvents = False` id used

---

**2nd "environment"**

You have cell(s) in your excel worksheet containing a formula, like:

```
="Dealer:" & CustomerName
```

where `CustomerName` is a *named range*

and your VBA code is going to modify the content of that named range

in this case the `Worksheet_Change()` sub would be triggered by the *named range* value change and not by the cell containing the formula

so I'd go checking if the changed cell is a `valid` one (i.e. corresponding to a `well known` named range) and then go with a sub that scans a predefined range and finds and format all cells with formulas that use that `named range, like follows (comments should help you):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Not Intersect(ActiveWorkbook.Names("CustomerName").RefersToRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False '<-- prevent this macro to be fired again and again by the statement following in two rows
            On Error GoTo ExitSub
            FormatCells Columns(1), "CustomerName" '<-- call a specific sub that will properly format all cells of passed range that contains reference to passed "named range" name
        End If
    End With

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- get standard event handling back
End Sub

Sub FormatCells(rng As Range, strngInFormula As String)
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) '<--| reference passed range cells containg formulas only
        Set f = .Find(what:=strngInFormula, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart) '<--| search for the first cell in the referenced range containing the passed formula part
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
            firstAddress = f.Address '<--| store first found cell address
            Do '<--| start looping through all possible matching criteria cells
                f.Value = f.Value '<--| change current cell content into text resulting from its formula
                f.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True '<--| make its first 7 characters bold
                Set f = .FindNext(f) '<--| search for next matching cell
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress '<--| exit loop before 'Find()' method wraps back to the first cell found
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**

My understanding is that the OP needs to have in cell `A5` the result of the formula `="Dealer: " & CustomerName` showing the `Dealer:` part in bold characters.
Now, what it is not clear, is the nature of the `CustomerName` part of the formula. This solution assumes it corresponds to a `Defined Name` with workbook scope *(let me know if different)*.

I assume that the reason for using a formula and not writing directly the result of the formula and formatting the `A5` cell with a VBA procedure is to allow users to see the data from different customers just by a calculation change in the workbook, rather than by running a VBA procedure.

Let say that we have the following data in a worksheet named `Report`, were the Defined Name `CustomerName` has a workbook scope and is hidden.
Located at `A5` is the formula `="Dealer: " & CustomerName`
The Fig.1 shows the report with the data for `Customer 1`.

[image]

Fig.1

Now if we change the Customer Number in cell `E3` to `4`, the report will show the data of the customer selected; without running any VBA procedure. Unfortunately as the cell `A5` contains a formula its contents font cannot be partially formatted to show “Dealer: ” in bold characters. The Fig.2 shows the report with the data for `Customer 4`.

[image]

Fig.2

The solution proposed herewith is to [Dynamically display the contents of a cell or range in a graphic object](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Dynamically-display-the-contents-of-a-cell-or-range-in-a-graphic-object-E2E7A629-5662-42D6-9295-06D112C2099F)

To implement this solution we need to recreate the desired Output Range and add a `Shape` in `A5` that will contain a link to the Output Range.
Assuming that we don’t want this Output Range to be seen in the same worksheet were the report is, and keeping mind that *the Output Range cells cannot be hidden*; let’s create this Output Range in another worksheet named “Customers Data” at `B2:C3` (see Fig.3). Enter in `B2` `Dealer:` and in `C2` enter the formula `=Customer Name` then format each cell as required (`B2` font bold, `C3` can have a different font type if you like – let’s apply font italic for this sample). Ensure the range have the appropriated width so the text does not overflows the cells.

[image]

Fig.3

It’s suggested to create a `Defined Name` for this range. The code below creates the `Defined Name` called `RptDealer`.

```
Const kRptDealer As String = "RptDealer" ‘Have this constant at the top of the Module. It is use by two procedures

Sub Name_ReportDealerName_Add()
'Change Sheetname "Customers Data" and Range "B2:C2" as required
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customers Data")
        .Cells(2, 2).Value = "Dealer: "
        .Cells(2, 2).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=CustomerName"  'Change as required
        .Cells(2, 3).Font.Italic = True
        With .Parent
            .Names.Add Name:=kRptDealer, RefersTo:=.Sheets("Customers Data").Range("B2:C2") ', _
                Visible:=False 'Visible is True by Default, use False want to have the Name hidden to users
            .Names(kRptDealer).Comment = "Name use for Dealer\Customer picture in report"
        End With
        .Range(kRptDealer).Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    End Sub
```

Following the above preparations , now we can create the Shape that will be linked to the Output Range named `RptDealer`. Select at cell `A5` in worksheet `Report` and follow the instructions for [Dynamically display cell range contents in a picture](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Dynamically-display-the-contents-of-a-cell-or-range-in-a-graphic-object-E2E7A629-5662-42D6-9295-06D112C2099F#bm3) or if you prefer use the code below to add and format the linked `Shape`.

```
Sub Shape_DealerPicture_Set(rCll As Range)
Const kShpName As String = "_ShpDealer"
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim shpTrg As Shape

    Rem Delete Dealer Shape if present and set Dealer Source Range
    On Error Resume Next
    rCll.Worksheet.Shapes(kShpName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Rem Set Dealer Source Range
    Set rSrc = ThisWorkbook.Names(kRptDealer).RefersToRange

    Rem Target Cell Settings & Add Picture Shape
    With rCll
        .ClearContents
        If .RowHeight < rSrc.RowHeight Then .RowHeight = rSrc.RowHeight
        If .ColumnWidth < rSrc.Cells(1).ColumnWidth + rSrc.Cells(2).ColumnWidth Then _
            .ColumnWidth = rSrc.Cells(1).ColumnWidth + rSrc.Cells(2).ColumnWidth
        rSrc.CopyPicture
        .PasteSpecial
        Selection.Formula = rSrc.Address(External:=1)
        Selection.PrintObject = msoTrue
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Goto .Cells(1)
        Set shpTrg = .Worksheet.Shapes(.Worksheet.Shapes.Count)
    End With

    Rem Shape Settings
    With shpTrg
        On Error Resume Next
        .Name = "_ShpDealer"
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Locked = msoFalse
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .Locked = msoTrue
    End With

    End Sub
```

The code above can be called using this procedure:

```
Sub DealerPicture_Apply()
Dim rCll As Range
    Set rCll = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(5, 1)
    Call Shape_DealerPicture_Set(rCll)
    End Sub
```

The end result is a Picture that behaves like a formula as it is linked to the Output Range containing the formula and format desired (see Fig.4)

[image]
Fig.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing you could simply obtain the cells and place it in a variable, and basically append it. From here you can use the .font.bold functionality to bold a specific part. Lets say on page 2, you have "Dealer: " in cell a1, and "Josh" in b1. Here is an example how it could be done:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, "a") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "a") & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "b")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, "a").Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True 'Bolds "dealer:" only.
```

Comment: Tried on my computer, bolds whole cell if applied to formula