# Export bold text to Outlook mail through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I pull commodity prices from a Bloomberg terminal and send a pricing update email to a set group of contacts.

An example of one output is:

> Iron Ore 62% Import Fine Ore: US$92.71, down from the prior closing price of US$93.61, up 31.4% YTD, and up 44.5% YoY.

Sourced via:

> =C5&" US"&TEXT(D5,"$#,##0.00")&", "&E5&" from the prior closing price of "&"US"&TEXT(F5,"$#,##0.00")&", "&G5&TEXT(H5," #,##0.0%; (#,##0.0%)")&" YTD, and "&I5&TEXT(J5," #,##0.0%; (#,##0.0%)")&" YoY."

with referenced cells being Bloomberg pulls.

The code opens a pre-filled Outlook email. I am trying to export a formatted output.

In the example above, I want the "US$92.71" to export to the email as bold.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016


' -------------------------------------------------------

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Range("S3:S26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("Output").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Cells(41, 2)
        .CC = Cells(41, 3)
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Cells(1, 12)
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
        '.Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I use this Ron de Bruin range to HTML method every day. If you have standard formatting that applies to the same cell in your copied range every time, try forcing the formatting in the tempfile in block `'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in` If you put a break at the end of that block, you can determine how the tempfile looks and what to format. From then it's standard text formatting.

Comment: After looking at it another time, it doesn't seem like the output macro is the issue, it's the way you generate your output with `=C5&" US"&TEXT(D5,"$#,##0.00")&", "&E5&" from the prior closing price of "&"US"&TEXT(F5,"$#,##0.00")&", "&G5&TEXT(H5," #,##0.0%; (#,##0.0%)")&" YTD, and "&I5&TEXT(J5," #,##0.0%; (#,##0.0%)")&" YoY."` since this is an excel formula, it cannot copy over formatting like **Bold**. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793924/bolding-a-specific-part-of-cell) might give you some insight on how to solve that. After that the export should work fine.

Comment: Did you understand Plutian's comment and did you understand what you needed to do to fix your code?